# How and where to add new bean in Sping application generated by Jhipster

Tags: spring, jhipster

I generated my Spring application using Jhipster. Now I want to add controller for FilesUpload, and  StorageService for it. But when I run my application it gets me this message

> Description:Parameter 0 of constructor in com.kongresspring.myapp.web.rest.FileUploadResource required a bean of type 'com.kongresspring.myapp.service.StorageService' that could not be found.
>   Action:Consider defining a bean of type 'com.kongresspring.myapp.service.StorageService' in your configuration.

I can't find beans.xml to add new bean. I'm new in spring, so maybe there's some other way to configure bean, I'm not familiar whit. Here's my code for uploading file controller:

```
package com.kongresspring.myapp.web.rest;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import com.kongresspring.myapp.service.StorageService;





@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FileUploadResource {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadResource.class);
private final StorageService storageService;

@Autowired
public FileUploadResource(StorageService storageService) {
    this.storageService = storageService;
}

/**
* POST uploadFile
*/
@PostMapping("/upload-file")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    storageService.store(file);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
        "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    return "success";
}

/**
* GET preview
*/
@GetMapping("/preview")
public String preview() {
    return "preview";
}



}
```

And here's my StorageService code:

```
package com.kongresspring.myapp.service;

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public interface StorageService {

void init();

void store(MultipartFile file);

Stream<Path> loadAll();

Path load(String filename);

Resource loadAsResource(String filename);



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an implementation for StorageService, and annotate it as @Service/@Component, spring will automatically discover the bean:

```
@Service
public class StorageServiceImpl implements StorageService {

void init(){// You code goes here/}

void store(MultipartFile file){///}

Stream<Path> loadAll(){///}

Path load(String filename){//}

Resource loadAsResource(String filename){///}

}
```